# PyUSB how to specify the type and the buffer size of the endpoint

Tags: python-2.7, usb, pyusb

There are four different ways to send data across USB: Control, Interrupt, Bulk, and Isochronous. [book ref 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=MTibAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT358&lpg=PT358&dq=usb.core%20set%20buffer%20size&source=bl&ots=ITFXpjNNxP&sig=fm3jViwWnAXtFJtYRtKoTZplaoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKt_X96LzbAhVMuVMKHXgSAcYQ6AEIXTAF#v=onepage&q=usb.core%20set%20buffer%20size&f=false)
From the book [book ref 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=MTibAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT358&lpg=PT358&dq=usb.core%20set%20buffer%20size&source=bl&ots=ITFXpjNNxP&sig=fm3jViwWnAXtFJtYRtKoTZplaoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKt_X96LzbAhVMuVMKHXgSAcYQ6AEIXTAF#v=onepage&q=usb.core%20set%20buffer%20size&f=false) page 330:

> ... Bulk endpoints transfer large amounts of data. These endpoints are usually much larger (they can hold more characters at once) that interrupt endpoints. ...

when I get my endpoint input I use the following command.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0683, idProduct=0x4108)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

dev.reset()
dev.set_configuration()
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]    

epi = usb.util.find_descriptor(
                              intf,
                              # match the first IN endpoint
                              custom_match = \
                              lambda e: \
                              usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) ==\
                              usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN)
```

I tried to add, but it give my a sytax error that I don't fully understand :

```
usb.util.endpoint_type()== \
                              usb.util.ENDPOINT_TYPE_BULK
```

[image]

Here is another very good source on how to work with USB [link 1](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#EndpointDescriptors)

It seems that usb endpoints have parameters that can be specified in python

[image]

where bEndpointAddress indicates what endpoint this descriptor is describing.

**bmAttributes** specifies the transfer type. This can either be Control, Interrupt, Isochronous or Bulk Transfers. If an Isochronous endpoint is specified, additional attributes can be selected such as the Synchronisation and usage types.

**wMaxPacketSize** indicates the maximum payload size for this endpoint.

**bInterval** is used to specify the polling interval of certain transfers. The units are expressed in frames, thus this equates to either 1ms for low/full speed devices and 125us for high speed devices.

I have tried:

```
epi.wMaxPacketSize = 72000000 #to make the buffer large
epi.bmAttributes = 3 # 3 = 10 in binary. to change the mode to bulk
```

My questions are:

Where do I specify what kind of endpoint I am using for Windows and(or) Linux and how to do that? and How can I change the buffer size on each endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
epi = usb.util.find_descriptor(intf,
                               custom_match = \
                                 lambda e: \
                                   usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
                                   usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN \
                                   and \
                                   usb.util.endpoint_type(e.bmAttributes) == \
                                   usb.util.ENDPOINT_TYPE_BULK )
```

But you misunderstood the part about the parameters. *bmAttributes* and *wMaxPacketSize* are specified by the USB hardware and not to be changed by Python.